# Why is `sudo make install` failing with "unrecognized relocation"?

Tags: software-installation, sudo, opensuse, path, toolchain

This is a question/answer post, intended for people encountering the same issue.

This problem only happens when using a separate toolchain (gcc, binutils, libtool) which is not in the standard path.

i.e., `which gcc` gives a location that is not listed by

```
sudo env | grep -w "PATH="
```

This was necessary to compile octave-4.2 on OpenSUSE 13.2 (the standard gcc was too old).

On a standard system, where there is only one toolchain, and this toolchain is in the standard path, `sudo make install` works just fine.

Here is the error, on `sudo make install`:

```
libtool: warning: relinking 'Magick++/lib/libGraphicsMagick++.la'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
Magick++/lib/.libs/Magick___lib_libGraphicsMagick___la-Image.o: unrecognized relocation (0x2a) in section `.text'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
libtool: error: error: relink 'Magick++/lib/libGraphicsMagick++.la' with the above command before installing it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the reason why:

The point was that the `configure` and `make` steps worked because the `PATH` was prepended with the location of the toolchain (e.g. `gcc`)

But [`sudo` does not propagate the variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83191/104955). 
Hence `sudo make install` ran commands with the wrong toolchain (the old `gcc` for instance).

One solution is to just use `su`

```
su
# make install
```